# Come with or go with?

Tags: grammar

The question is about “Can you please _______ with me?”

Options are:

> Can you please come with me?
> Can you please go with me?

Please advise me which is correct.

Comment: Could be either, depending on the situation.

Comment: When you say the options are two, does it ean you eliminated a third or fourth contender. Where did you find this exercise, was it online or in a scholastic text?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I eliminated the third and fourth contenders which OP didn't remember, in the edit, which you might be obliquely referencing.

Answer (score 1):

Usually "come with me", since you will not "go" away from the speaker, but stay close to them.  However, it is easy to think of contexts in which "go with me" is expected, for example, if "go" is already established.  "I'm going to the shops, would you like to go with me."

If the speaker means "I will lead you somewhere", then "come with me" is the best choice.  But if the speaker means "I want you to lead me somewhere" then "Go" might be preferred.

> I can show you where the meeting room is.  Come with me, please.

> I'm scared to go into the haunted house. Please go with me.